# Spring boot application.yml locale

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, locale

In my project I need to send emails to customers in different languages in Spring Boot. The website is in english for now, only the emails sent must support different languages.

I tried to set all the languages supported in the application.yml file using the locale with the code snippet as follows: (other values are defined before)

```yaml
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 15MB
  jackson:
    parser:
      allow-unquoted-control-chars: true
  web:
    locale:
      - en_GB
      - de_DE
      - fr_FR
      - es_ES
```

In the class where I use these locale, I tried to implement it in this way (with normally more arguments in the constructor):

```java
CommunicationService(@Value("{'${spring.web.locale}'.split(',')}") String[] localeList) {
    this.localeList = localeList;
}
```

When I try to run the tests, I get the following error

```java
Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.web.locale' in value "{'${spring.web.locale}'.split(',')}""
```

How could I fix this issue? How can I set more than one locale? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't need `.split(',')` as in yaml it is presented as list and also in the SPEL expression `#` is missing, can you try and replace it with `@Value("${spring.web.locale}") String[] localeList` or use `@Value("#{'${spring.web.locale}'.split(',')}") String[] localeList`